# how to file upload from an http client to an http server?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to convert the protocol my clients and servers use in a program from ftp to http but I have no idea even where to begin with the plethora of modules that exist. should I be using the request module? http module? The act of uploading a single text file is so simple yet I cannot seem to find a straight answer.

Comment: If this is a file uploaded as form data you might also consider [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable)

Answer (score 0):

request module is wrapper over http module...

Anyways you can use any, but point to upload is you have to set content-type header correctly, mostly it is multipart/form-data.

You should use something like POSTMAN or ADVANCE REST CLIENT(ARC) from chrome extensions and  try out the request to server and with same set of headers you can use in http module.